# Deserialize Json string from MVC action to C# Class

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, json

I have an Ajax call (for a HighChartsDB chart) in a WebForm application that calls a webservice, which uses a `WebRequest` to call an MVC action in another application which returns a JsonResult.

I manage to pass the data back to the ajax call but the data I get back is not parsed as a json object but just a string.

My class:

```
public class CategoryDataViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<int> data { get; set; }
    public double pointStart { get; set; }
    public int pointInterval { get { return 86400000; } }
}
```

My ajax function called by the highcharts:

```
function getBugs(mileId) {
    var results;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Services/WebService.svc/GetData',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        data: { "mileId": parseInt(mileId) },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            results = data;
        }
    });

    return results;
}
```

And finally my WebService

```
public class WebService : IWebService
{
    public string GetData(int mileId)
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:63418/Home/GetWoWData?mileId=" + mileId;
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);

        using (var response= (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return objText;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

With this when I console.log(data) on the ajax call I get:

```
[{\"name\":\"Sedan\",\"data\":[30,30,30,30,35],\"pointStart\":1307836800000,\"pointInterval\":86400000},{\"name\":\"Low\",\"data\":[800,800,800,826,1694],\"pointStart\":1307836800000,\"pointInterval\":86400000},{\"name\":\"Medium\",\"data\":[180,180,180,186,317],\"pointStart\":1307836800000,\"pointInterval\":86400000},{\"name\":\"High\",\"data\":[29,29,29,34,73],\"pointStart\":1307836800000,\"pointInterval\":86400000},{\"name\":\"Truck\",\"data\":[6,6,6,6,13],\"pointStart\":1307836800000,\"pointInterval\":86400000},{\"name\":\"SUV\",\"data\":[-172,-172,-172,-179,-239],\"pointStart\":1307836800000,\"pointInterval\":86400000},{\"name\":\"Convertible\",\"data\":[0,0,0,0,-404],\"pointStart\":1307836800000,\"pointInterval\":86400000},{\"name\":\"Limo\",\"data\":[-7,-7,-7,-8,-214],\"pointStart\":1307836800000,\"pointInterval\":86400000}]
```

I can't seem to manage to pass back into a proper Json object. I tried converting it back to my CategoryDataViewModel with this in my webservice:

```
    var myojb = new CategoryDataViewModel ();
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response .GetResponseStream()))
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            myojb = (CategoryDataViewModel )js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(CategoryDataViewModel ));
        }
    }

    return myojb;
```

But then I get `Type 'Test.CategoryDataViewModel' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
myojb = (CategoryDataViewModel )js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(CategoryDataViewModel ));
```

to:

```
myojb = (List<CategoryDataViewModel> )js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(List<CategoryDataViewModel>));
```

and you should be fine. The array will de-serialize to a list no problem.

Comment: myojb needs to be redefined as a List<CategoryDataViewModel> too.

Comment: Damn I actually tried that but I had left on the ajax part a `result = JSON.stringyfy(data)` by mistake... thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a similar thing before, I think you might need to change myObj to a list.

```
List<CategoryDataViewModel> myObjs = new List<CategoryDataViewModel>();
...
myObjs = js.Deserialize<List<CategoryDataViewModel>>(objText);
```

Comment: Apologies to Joey, he got there first, but for some reason it didn't alert me to any answers.