# How I can parse a json sended using ajax (POST) to NameValueCollection Class?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

Hollo:

I'm sending the following message to mi asp.net web api

```
var user ={
            Username: "user",
            Password: "pass"

        };
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://WebApiDir',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(user),
            success: function (data) {

            },
        });
```

I Caught the request on a DelegatingHandler.
My question is How to parse the message included on the HttpContent to a NameValueCollection class

I try do the following

```
var sQuery = await request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;
```

but this produce a exception becase the Result attr is null.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't allowing the WebAPI routing to deserialize your data as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I do:-

```
  $.ajax
                        ({
                            url: 'Default.aspx/MyMethod',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: ID }),
                            success: onSuccess,
                            fail: onFail
                        });
```

and then on the C# side:-

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        // MyMethod is used to pass Identifcation number from client side to server side via Ajax.
        public static string MyMethod(string ID)
        {
              ........ do whatever needs to be done ........

              return string.Format("Thanks for calling me with Ajax, the ID: " + data);
        }
```

Comment: This is not optimal if the user is actually using WebAPI as indicated by the tags

Comment: check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383098/creating-json-return-strings-from-a-webservice-for-use-with-jquery-ajax?rq=1

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128792/deserialize-json-string-from-mvc-action-to-c-sharp-class?rq=1

maybe these will give you more ideas.




and

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using WebAPI, you should allow the framework to do the heavy lifting for you.

First, you need to make sure that your routing is set up correctly and that you are actually calling the route from your javascript.  In your case, App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs would look something like:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Then, give your api controller a meaningful name name such as Users and define the method as a post, since you are posting user info, taking User as a parameter

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public string Post(User user)
{
    // perform actions on user data
    return "success";
}
```

Finally, you need to properly define the route in your javascript call.

```
var user ={
    Username: "user",
    Password: "pass"
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://WebApiDir.com/api/Users',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: user,
    success: function (data){},
});
```

Comment: I have not problem with that the method its called. The problem that i have is that I can't catch the content in the handler

Comment: What does your handler look like?

Comment: It's something like this:                                                _NameValueCollection query = request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result; italic_  This produce a NameValueCollection empty

Comment: My question is, why are you reading from the request content when you can take it as a parameter on your web api method?

Comment: becase I have authentication data that I need catch on the handler